# append build number from azure pipeline to update AssemblyVersion in AssemblyInfo.cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, azure-pipelines

I have a wpf project. And have a branch in my azure repo for the project. I have created a `CommonAssemblyInfo.cs` file under properties folder in my project. In that file I have AssemblyVersion information as below:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.0.1")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.0.1")]
```

I am trying to use `task: Assembly-Info-NetFramework@3` in my `azure-pipelines.yml` file of the branch for project after the `build` stage as below:

```
- stage: Versioning
  displayName:'Automate versioning'
  jobs:
  - job: Set build number and version
    steps:
    - task: Assembly-Info-NetFramework@3
      inputs:
        Path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        FileNames: '**\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs'
        InsertAttributes: true
        FileEncoding: 'auto'
        WriteBOM: false
        Title: 'Update AssemblyVersion for WFE'
        Product: 'WFE'
        VersionNumber: '${Build.BuildNumber}'
        FileVersionNumber: '$(appVersion)'
        InformationalVersion: '$(appVersion)'
        LogLevel: 'verbose'
        FailOnWarning: false
        DisableTelemetry: false
```

But it is not updating the assembly version.
My question is How can I append build number from Azure pipeline when I commit my new work to the branch and append to AssemblyVersion?

Answer (score 0):

Please try extension [Update AssemblyInfo](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sebastianlux.UpdateAssemblyInfo), it works as expected.

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: Update AssemblyInfo@1
  inputs:
    rootFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    filePattern: 'CommonAssemblyInfo.cs'
    assemblyVersion: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    assemblyFileVersion: '$(appVersion)'
    assemblyInformationalVersion: '$(appVersion)'
```

You can also using other extensions like [Replace Text in Source Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Samayas.azuredevops-samayas-replaceinfiles) to search and replace the corresponding versions with variables.

Comment: Currently I don't have permission to add this task into the task list of azure devops pipeline